# Xtensor: can't reach numpy performance

Tags: python, c++, cmake, xtensor

I'm learning [xtensor](https://github.com/QuantStack/xtensor) and want to get the same or even higher performance then NumPy. But unfortunately, I can't and need help.

I did similar benchmark as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240338/performance-of-xtensor-types-vs-numpy-for-simple-reduction):

[Performance of xtensor types vs. NumPy for simple reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240338/performance-of-xtensor-types-vs-numpy-for-simple-reduction)

This is C++ code, where I used pybind11 and [xtensor-python](https://github.com/QuantStack/xtensor-python)

`bench.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define XTENSOR_USE_XSIMD
#include "xtensor/xtensor.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xfixed.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xarray.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xio.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xview.hpp"
#define FORCE_IMPORT_ARRAY                // numpy C api loading
#include "xtensor-python/pytensor.hpp"
#include "xtensor-python/pyarray.hpp"

namespace py = pybind11;

inline double sum_pytensor(xt::pytensor<double, 1> &m)
{
  return xt::sum(m)();
}



inline double sum_pytensor_immediate(xt::pytensor<double, 1> &m)
{
  return xt::sum(m, xt::evaluation_strategy::immediate)();
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(xtensor_basics, m)
{
    xt::import_numpy();

    m.def("compute_xtensor", &sum_pytensor);
    m.def("compute_xtensor_immediate", &sum_pytensor_immediate);
}
```

I build this with CMake

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(xtensor_basics)

add_definitions(-DXTENSOR_ENABLE_XSIMD) # <-- does this anything?
add_definitions(-DXTENSOR_USE_XSIMD)
add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(xtensor_basics bench.cpp)

include_directories(/home/--user--/include)
include_directories(/home/--user--/.miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include)
```

and the following command: `cmake . && make` which creates `xtensor_basics.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Then I run the benchmark with this python file:
`bench.py`

```py
import timeit

def time_each(func_names, sizes):
    setup = f'''
import numpy; import xtensor_basics
arr = numpy.random.randn({sizes})
    '''
    tim = lambda func: min(timeit.Timer(f'{func}(arr)',
                                        setup=setup).repeat(3, 100))
    return [tim(func) for func in func_names]

from functools import partial

sizes = [10 ** i for i in range(7)]
funcs = ['numpy.sum',
         'xtensor_basics.compute_xtensor_immediate',
         'xtensor_basics.compute_xtensor']
sum_timer = partial(time_each, funcs)
times = list(map(sum_timer, sizes))
print(times)
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

plt.Figure(figsize=(5, 10))
plt.plot(times)
plt.legend(["numpy", "xtensor_immediate", "xtensor"])
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

**Directory** (after building)

```
bench.cpp
bench.py
CMakeCache.txt
CMakeFiles
cmake_install.cmake
CMakeLists.txt
Makefile
pybind11            <---clonned from the repo
xtensor_basics.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

**Include dirrectory**
All folders containing headers (I didn't build these libraries, just copied headers)

```
$ ls /home/--user--/include -1
   xflens
   xsimd
   xtensor
   xtensor-blas
   xtensor-python
   xtl
```

**System**

```
Ubuntu                         18.04
g++                            7.4.0
numpy                          1.16.4
openblas                       0.2.20
python                         3.7.3
xtensor                        0.20.8
```

**Question**: What flags, definitions etc. should I add to get the same performance?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: 1**
When I built with `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .`, i.e enabling optimisations, the result has improved, but still slower:
[image]

Comment: Think you need an optimised release build

Comment: @AshotMatevosyan Is this question still relevant ? Or has the latest release fixed this ?

Answer (score 4):

Change `CMakeLists.txt` a bit:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(xtensor_basics)

add_definitions(-DXTENSOR_ENABLE_XSIMD)
add_definitions(-DXTENSOR_USE_XSIMD)\
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -O3 -mavx2 -ffast-math")
#                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(xtensor_basics bench.cpp)

include_directories(/home/--user--/include)
include_directories(/home/--user--/.miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include)
```

and... Victory! 
[image]

Comment: Where is numpy in this plot?

Comment: I am suprised that `evaluation_strategy::immediate` here makes a difference!